# Can you resolve a droplink to an item within a GraphQL?

Tags: graphql

I have a template with a droplink "productarea". When I use a GraphQL to fetch this item, the value of the "productarea" is a GUID. This guid points to an item in the sitecore tree, and I need the displayName of that item. Is this possible to get using a single GraphQL, or do I need to run a second GraphQL from the client?

Here are the queries I'm using:

```
query getArticles($item: String = "{02E9F5E2-8CDE-4A52-B260-62B628692BF8}") {
  item(path: $item) {
    ...articleFields
  }
}

fragment articleFields on ArticlePage {
  productarea{
    value
  }
}

query getArea($item: String = "{ADAA9D5C-4C30-477B-960A-0062B384F235}") {
  item(path: $item) {
    displayName
  }
}
```

Get articles result:

```
{
  "data": {
    "item": {
      "productarea": {
        "value": "{ADAA9D5C-4C30-477B-960A-0062B384F235}"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

GetArea result

```
{
  "data": {
    "item": {
      "displayName": "Doors"
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can resolve a Sitecore Droplink to an Item in one query, a Droplink has a targetItem that is the way to access the fields of the reference in GraphQL.

GraphQL Example:

```
query getArticles($item: String = "{02E9F5E2-8CDE-4A52-B260-62B628692BF8}") {
  item(path: $item) {
    ...articleFields
  }
}

fragment articleFields on ArticlePage {
  productarea{
    value
    targetItem {
      displayName
   }
  }
```

Where productarea is a Droplink field on template ArticlePage and the provided GUID {02E9F5E2-8CDE-4A52-B260-62B628692BF8} is the ArticlePage Item from the content tree.

Comment: That worked like a charm, thank you ever so much